# FTP access into Azure where there are two Websites

Tags: azure, ftp, orchardcms

I have 2 web sites in my Azure account and I would like to access the second one via FTP, however, when I load up the FTP site I am getting the FTP area for the first site and I cannot see any data for my second site.

My first site is a straightforward web site, but the second is an Orchard template. I was expecting to see the Orchard folder structure when I accessed the FTP area but seems only the first site is accessible via FTP.

I have looked at other threads about setting up your own FTP but I would like to avoid doing that until it is absolutely necessary.

**So my question:** Does anyone know if the Orchard website, generated by Azure, is accessible via FTP, or to get access can I safely reset the credentials from the dashboard on the second website so it has its own FTP area via an individual set of credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the username you use for FTP should be `<web site name>\<username>`, so you should already have different credentials for the two sites. Can you confirm you're using the right credentials to try to access the Orchard site? Check the "deployment user" on the right-hand side in the portal and make sure you're using that.

Comment: Yes you are correct my FTP tool was using the wrong part for the `<web site name>`. Have changed it and I can confirm I do have access now. Thanks.

Comment: Everyday Azure is surprising me by a such no-sense.... why not a simple ftp://DOMAIN with your Azure login/password

Comment: @ThomasDecaux I'm not 100% sure what you're talking about, but if you're suggesting removing the website name from the username and instead putting it elsewhere (a subdomain for the FTP server, for example), I think the issue is that FTP doesn't have the equivalent of an HTTP "host" header, so there's no way for the server to know which domain you used (so it doesn't know which website you're trying to edit). So to make this scheme work, you'd need a separate IP address for every website, which doesn't scale.

Comment: I believed it was possible (see http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.ftpserver/serverruntime/hostnamesupport)

Comment: Cool! I stand corrected. This might be a good thing to suggest to Microsoft (though this Q&A is over two years old, so maybe things have changed already).

Comment: @smarx - It no longer appears to be true that different websites in the same sub have different credentials.  Its true that the username prefix is <websitename> but when you set a <username> on any of your sites, the last one wins and is global.  Same for the password.  This is confirmed per text on the 'Set Deployment Credentials' blade: "Use this user name and password to deploy to any apps for all subscriptions associated with your Microsoft Azure account"